# Custom uploads on Tinydrive

Tags: upload, tinymce, handler

I'm newbie on Tiny and I'm trying Tinydrive right now, after implement TinyMCE in my solution. I've just put some lines of code to upload images to my own repository, when I upload one with TinyMCE (using images_upload_handler as option). This calls an .ashx controler who catch files and upload to my S3 storage.
My question is, is there any way to do this with Tinydrive? Then, I could browse all files stored there. As far I could see, it uploads images and files to its own S3 Amazon storage, but I can't find any to way to specify where the files have to place to, beyond Dropbox or Google Drive integrations.

Cheers.